# Scrapy spider extension fails to log DB pipeline errors

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to add a signal to my scrapy extension for sending me an email whenever there are errors via the `spider_error` signal. Even when there are errors in the pipeline, it looks it these errors are not being logged by the spider signal or the spider is not responsible after the item is scraped and in the pipeline ? Is there a way I can log these from the extension instead ? Here's the code to my extension which collects that stats for each spider in DB and next I was trying to email the errors, whose signal doesn't seem to trigger:

```
class StatsCollectorExtension(object):
    def __init__(self, stats):
        self.stats = stats
        self.num_errors = 0
        self.errors = []

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        ext = cls(crawler.stats)
        crawler.signals.connect(ext.spider_error, signal=signals.spider_error)
        crawler.signals.connect(ext.spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)
        return ext

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        """
        When the spider closes then
        store the stats(start time, end time, items scraped,
        pages crawled) into the database for each scraper.
        Also send the errors through email if any.
        """
        start_time = self.stats._stats['start_time']
        finish_time = self.stats._stats['finish_time']
        items_scraped_count = self.stats._stats['item_scraped_count']
        spider_name = spider.name
        pages_crawled_count = self.stats._stats['downloader/request_method_count/GET']

        # add the scrapy stats to DB via SQL Alchemy object
        stats = ScrapyStats(scrapername=spider_name,
                            start_time=start_time,
                            finish_time=finish_time,
                            items_scraped=items_scraped_count,
                            pages_crawled=pages_crawled_count)
        db_session.add(stats)
        db_session.commit()

        if self.num_errors:
            # Mandrill mail client that sends me an email
            html = ''.join(self.errors)
            subject = '%s errors found' % self.num_errors
            send_mail(subject, from_email, from_name,
                      html, to_email, to_mail, mandrill_key)

    def spider_error(self, failure, response, spider):
        self.errors.append(failure.getTraceback())
        self.num_errors += 1
```

Also heres the stacktrace

```
2015-01-08 13:13:20-0500 [ferc-staff-reports] ERROR: Error processing {'additional_documents': None,
     'ekwhere': 'Fed',
     'id': 'FERCaeff76181cc2bc14651c693d30300b99a7673219',
     'publishdate': datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 30, 0, 0),
     'title': 'The IV Formulation and Linear Approximations of the AC Optimal Power Flow Problem: Optimal Power Flow Paper 2',
     'type': 'FERC Staff Reports & Papers - Staff Papers',
     'url': u'http://www.ferc.gov/industries/electric/indus-act/market-planning/opf-papers/acopf-2-iv-linearization.pdf'}
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 62, in _process_chain
        return process_chain(self.methods[methodname], obj, *args)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 65, in process_chain
        d.callback(input)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 382, in callback
        self._startRunCallbacks(result)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 490, in _startRunCallbacks
        self._runCallbacks()
    --- <exception caught here> ---
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 577, in _runCallbacks
        current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
      File "/home/kiran/workspace/EK-source-scrapers/helpers/pipelines.py", line 88, in process_item
        insert_item(item, spider.settings["table"])
      File "/home/kiran/workspace/EK-source-scrapers/helpers/db_helper.py", line 54, in insert_item
        db_session.commit()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 149, in do
        return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 765, in commit
        self.transaction.commit()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 370, in commit
        self._prepare_impl()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 350, in _prepare_impl
        self.session.flush()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1879, in flush
        self._flush(objects)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1997, in _flush
        transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 57, in __exit__
        compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1961, in _flush
        flush_context.execute()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 370, in execute
        rec.execute(self)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 523, in execute
        uow
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 64, in save_obj
        mapper, table, insert)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 562, in _emit_insert_statements
        execute(statement, multiparams)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 717, in execute
        return meth(self, multiparams, params)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 317, in _execute_on_connection
        return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 814, in _execute_clauseelement
        compiled_sql, distilled_params
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 927, in _execute_context
        context)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1076, in _handle_dbapi_exception
        exc_info
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 185, in raise_from_cause
        reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 920, in _execute_context
        context)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 425, in do_execute
        cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
        self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
        raise errorclass, errorvalue
    sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) (1054, "Unknown column 'additional_documents' in 'field list'") 'INSERT INTO sourceferc (id, title, url, type, publishdate, scrapedate, ekwhere, summary, docket_no, additional_documents) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)' ('FERCaeff76181cc2bc14651c693d30300b99a7673219', 'The IV Formulation and Linear Approximations of the AC Optimal Power Flow Problem: Optimal Power Flow Paper 2', u'http://www.ferc.gov/industries/electric/indus-act/market-planning/opf-papers/acopf-2-iv-linearization.pdf', 'FERC Staff Reports & Papers - Staff Papers', datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 30, 0, 0), datetime.date(2015, 1, 8), 'Fed', None, None, None)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is not something you can catch with built-in spider signals since a spider has done it's job without errors here. The error was raised later while processing item and inserting it into the database in the pipeline.

What options you should consider:

- modify the pipeline and raise [`DropItem("Database error %s" % error)`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exceptions.html#scrapy.exceptions.DropItem) on error - in this case you can listen for [`item_dropped` signal](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html#scrapy.signals.item_dropped)
- since having a database synchronized with your sqlalchemy models is, strictly speaking, a prerequisite/requirement for your project to run - may be better check it on initialization step and do not allow the spider to even start crawling if there is an error

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I guess this sounds like a more plausible way to do it. Thank you. I am gonna try doing that now.

Comment: Got it working! Now I wish I could give you a double up for that answer :)